# Use fingerprint for scrolling

Tags: fingerprint-reader

Is it possible to use fingerprint to scroll?
If yes how can i use it for scrolling?
My laptop‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌ is hp pavilion dm4.

Comment: Fingerprint readers are for fingerprint detection only.

Comment: It is an old wish: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.20/+bug/121967  @CelticWarrior it is technically possible but we (at the minimum) lack the software implementation for it.

Comment: similar feature request from 2011 https://www.mail-archive.com/fprint@reactivated.net/msg01702.html but no response, maybe ask https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/Mailing_list/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches and try some ways I get this it's mpossible to scroll with fingerprint.